# want to enable and disable sets of Vuforia Image Targets in Unity but not working as expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

New-ish at the Vuforia combo with Unity.  So hope this makes sense as a question to get some help on a simple Unity AR find the right Image target (with animated characters) game.

Using Unity, I've got 3 sets of Vuforia Image Targets (3 images in each set) that i'm using for this find the right image target game.  I want them to be played in order, set 1, then set 2, then set 3.  So in Unity, i call a little script that turns on set 1 image targets using ImageTarget1.SetActive (true) for all those markrs and  Set.Active(false) for the markers in set 2 and set 3.

Once the user views the right image target in Set 1, I call an event that call the reset function that sets Set 1 Image Markers to False and Set 2 Image Markers to true.  Same for moving to Set 3, then end game.

I'm thinking this is the way to do it, all markers are in the room, but they are not activated unles their set is on.

Here is what happens.  I do move thru the Sets as sets of Image Markers, I see them come on in Unity and turn off in order.  But, when they come on, they all play at once and not because of the camera picking up a marker.  By all play at once I mean they run their animators with their attached audio files all staring at the same instant, the instant their set it turned on.  No visual unless I get one of the cards in front of the camera quick, they all run thru their aninations in their animators and boom the next set is on and so fort.

I call the sets into SetActive(true) at the very end of the final animation of the right target to find in a set, so its a unique animator and within the final animation that is also unique.  I'm being super careful there, in case its something to do with reusing an animation with events, I've made full dups and renamed them.

I would just love any insights on this, I'm kind of shocked it is not working.  But it is my first real effort on using the Vuforia Image Markers with added logic around them in Unity.  The SetActive is all Unity to me, no Vuforia, just they exist or they don't so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

:-) love any help!  Can paste in images and code if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK seems a common issue with Vuforia, so I worked around it with Unity in the C# to disable the marker objects but not the markers.  Just in case anyone needs this insight.  I had wanted to do it in Vuforia but this works for now. :-)